# Is heat kinetic energy or changes in electron energy levels? or both?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, atomic-physics, atoms

Both sort of make sense, but some sources say that it's vibrations while others say it's electron level change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heat is a transfer of energy from an object with higher temperature to an object with lower temperature. I think what you actually wanted to know is if thermal energy is associated with vibrations or electronic excitations.

Thermal energy is energy that is stored in the internal degrees of freedom that we cannot keep track of individually. This includes microscopic vibrations, rotations, bending, torsion, kinetic energy, chemical bonds, and electronic excitations. At high enough temperatures it even includes nuclear excitations. Basically, it includes everywhere that energy can be stored inside an object.

One characteristic of thermal energy is that it is equally likely to be in any of the accessible internal degrees of freedom. Sometimes, one particular degree of freedom is excited more than others, due to some external work. That energy can be transferred to other degrees of freedom to become “thermalized”. For example, when friction does work on an object the bending degrees of freedom are preferentially excited. That energy rapidly transfers into other internal degrees of freedom, thus becoming thermal energy. The result is the familiar observation that the object becomes hotter.

Answer (score 5):

> Is heat kinetic energy or changes in electron levels? or both?

It is neither.

Heat is *energy transfer* due solely to temperature difference. It is a mechanism for transferring energy. The other mechanism is work.

Therefore heat  can cause a change in internal kinetic energy of a substance or cause a  change in electron energy level, but it is not the energy of the electron itself or  the kinetic energy of the substance itself.

Hope this helps